# Laravel: How to override route helper function for a named route

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have working on predeveloped Laravel-5.x project and I need to change lots of URLs from:

```
route('product.show', ['id'=> $product->id), 'title' => $product->title])
```

to

```
route('product.show', ['id'=> encode_id($product->id), 'title' => slug_title($product->title)])
```

If I don't want replace all the 'product.show' routes to new version, is there any way to override route helper function for 'product.show' to generate new URL?

Comment: Maybe just use Find & Replace function provided with probably every editory/IDE.

Comment: You can probably override the route method if you define it in your app's bootstrap file. However you probably don't want to do that. Just do a find/replace.

Comment: @wolen and @apokryfos it is a bit hard because the `$product` variable name changed in some where

Comment: @ma.mehralian so, if previous code worked maybe it's possible to use ```encode_id()``` and ```slug_title()``` in controller instead? I don't know your code, just a shot :p.

Answer (score 1):

Function `route()` defined in the `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`

It is defined without any namespace thus it can be called anywhere. Obviously you can overwrite it in your project for example in the `AppServiceProvider` or `RouteServiceProvider`.

But I recommend you to use your custom function with some namespace that you should specify in the file(s) that you need.